# How to synchronize database with server

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have the following problem.

I'm on a project that was created using the framework phonegap (html + css + js). At one time we were needing to create a database in the app, so we use WebSQL which is a database used in html5.

Now I'm needing to access that database with objective-c, to synchronize data with the server.

Is there any way to access that database that is WebSQL?